# What a Ruby parser would you suggest to parse Ruby sources?

Tags: ruby, parsing

A parser I'm looking for should:

- be Ruby parsing friendly,
- be elegant by rule design,
- produce user friendly parsing errors,
- user documentation should be available in volume more than a calculator example,
- **UPD**: allowing to omit optional whitespaces writing a grammar.

Fast parsing is not an important feature.

I tried Citrus but the lack of documentation and need to specify every space in rules just turned me away from it.

Comment: What version of Ruby syntax are you needing to support?

Comment: Well, if you are willing to spend time on it, Ragel may be your best bet.

Comment: Version of Ruby as an input language does not matter much for my project because only a subset of the language will be implemented - 1.8 or 1.9 for example. Thanks, rmk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/)
- [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/)

Or in case you want to parse Ruby itself:

[parse_tree and ruby_parser](http://parsetree.rubyforge.org/)

Edit:

I just saw your last comment about needing a subset of Ruby for your project, in that case I'd also recommend having a look at [tinyrb](http://code.macournoyer.com/tinyrb/).

Comment: However *treetop/citrus* grammars are hard to write because of need to specify optional whitespaces *after every element* x_X. Ragel is recommended just for the lex work at the official web site; I will look at it however.

Comment: Thanks Michael! **Treetop** is rather a quick tool; I need to specify each whitespace manually but it's not a big pain.